# Создать файл в определённой директории

Tags: google-apps-script

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом, есть код

```
DriveApp.createFile(xlsxBlob.setName(`${exportSheetName}.xlsx`));
```

который создаёт файл в корневой директории google disc, хочу что бы создавал файл в указанной мной папке:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1xUWB-2Ye7Q1akfPDGf6ob_MEzPcrPsk4");
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

после 
`var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1xUWB-2Ye7Q1akfPDGf6ob_MEzPcrPsk4")`
Остается написать:
`folder.createFile(xlsxBlob.setName(${exportSheetName}.xlsx))`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.